# How to find data whose state got change within 72 hours in PostgreSql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp

I have my below table and I am working with PostgreSql-

```
name   state    col        UPDATED_DATE
abc     h1      1.0         2013-12-11 02:00:00.716897
def     h2      1.0         2013-12-15 02:00:00.716897
abc     h3      1.0         2013-12-11 03:00:00.716897
ghi     h4      1.0         2013-12-15 02:00:00.716897
def     h5      1.0         2013-12-16 02:00:00.716897
```

In the above table - I am supposed to find those name whose state was `h1`, `h2` or `h4` and got changed to `h3` within 72 hours. So if you see my above example -

state of name `abc` changed from `h1` to `h3` within 72 hours. So I should get this back as a result.

How do I write such query in PostgreSql? I have recently started working with PostgreSql.

This is how I tried writing a query:

```
select name
from table testState
Where updated_date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 48 HOUR)
and  updated_date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 72 HOUR)
and state='h3'(//I am not sure how to check this condition in SQL which is changes from state h1 to h3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
select distinct name
from (
  select name, 
         state, 
         col, 
         updated_date, 
         lag(state) over (partition by name order by UPDATED_DATE) as prev_state,
         lag(updated_date) over (partition by name order by UPDATED_DATE) as last_update
  from testState
) t 
where updated_date - last_update <= interval '48' hour
  and state = 'h3'
  and prev_state = 'h1'
```

This will however not work if there was a different state change in between (e.g. from h1 to h2 then to h3). If that case needs to be taken into account, this could be done in a more general way:

```
select distinct name
from (
  select name, 
         max(case when state = 'h1' then updated_date end) as h1_change,
         max(case when state = 'h3' then updated_date end) as h3_change
  from testState
  where state in ('h1', 'h3')
  group by name
) t
where h3_change - h1_change <= interval '48' hour;
```

If there can be more than one `h1` (and `h3`) entry, you might want adjust the usage of `max()` in the second query. `max()` always selects the latest change, if you want e.g. the first `h1` change, then use `min()` for the `h1_change` column.

Here is an SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b17c1/2

Comment: Thank you so much a_horse_with_no_name, its a really nice put up. So if in case I have a distinct name say, abc which was in state `H1` or `H2` or `H4` and then it got converted into state `H3` within given interval, can I still be able to use the same above query? by changing this `max(case when state = 'h1' or state ='h2' or state='h4' then updated_date end) as h1_change`

Comment: @akiiddweeber: yes that's still possible. But the only time you need to decide between min and max is when you have more than one entry for the same state. Otherwise it doesn't matter

Comment: Thank you a_horse_with_no_name, so if I need to query for names that are either in three of these states so I can do it as I have shown above? please correct me if I am wrong, also, I might have several entries in my database with the same name, and I needed all the changed ones, n ot just the latest and first one so how do you suggest I need to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

This query returns a set in which each row includes the next updated date.

```
  select 
    name, state, col, updated_date, 
    (select min(t.updated_date) 
     from test t 
     where t.name = test.name 
       and t.updated_date > test.updated_date) next_updated_date
  from test;
```

Now you can use that in another query, and do simple date arithmetic. There's more than one way to use that in another query; I'm using a common table expression.

```
with next_updated_dates as (
  select 
    name, state, col, updated_date, 
    (select min(t.updated_date) 
     from test t 
     where t.name = test.name 
       and t.updated_date > test.updated_date) next_updated_date
  from test
)
select *
from next_updated_dates
where next_updated_date - updated_date <= interval '48' hour;
```